# How to change the default user name from ubuntu to something else on EC2 AMI

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, user-management

How can I create a new Ubuntu AMI so that when a new instance is created the SSH credentials are copied under a different user than `ubuntu` (e.g. `/home/administrator/.ssh/`)?

In short, I need to be able to use username `administrator` instead of `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the EC2 user data to do so. Simply launch an AWS instance and place the following in the user data field:

```
#cloud-config
system_info:
  default_user:
    name: my_user_name
```

I wrote a detailed article on this process and it is available at https://emagalha.es/blog/2018/01/21/customizing-the-default-user-of-an-ubuntu-ami/

Answer (score -1):

I Believe this will work for you:

```
usermod -l new_name old_name
```

Comment: I need to have a new instance launched with this new user instead of ubuntu.

Comment: type `su new_name` and enter the chosen password

Answer (score -1):

Launch an instance with the 'ubuntu' username, change the user name as indicated by Nathan Cazell then create a new AMI from that instance and launch that.

Comment: I figured it out - you would have to set the user attribute to the username you want in the /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg file.